# CBCentralManager how to send passkey?

Tags: ios5, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new to BLE, and the LE security says it supports passkey Just Works, Out of Band and Passkey Entry. Given scenarios that the devices expects the passkey, then how to pass it through CentralManager while connecting to peripheral?.. Or do we have any alternate way to communicate with Security Manager ? Kindly provide the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

See the Bluetooth Guidlines from apple. There stands that the peripheral musst send a insuffiezient autorization. Then IOS do all automatic